# Shuffle 2 php arrays in the same way

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

I have this for example:

```
$array['one'][0] = 0;
$array['one'][1] = 1;
$array['one'][2] = 2;
$array['one'][3] = 3;

$array['two'][0] = 00;
$array['two'][1] = 11;
$array['two'][2] = 22;
$array['two'][3] = 33;
```

How can I shuffle them both to get something like:

```
$array['one'][0] = 2;
$array['one'][1] = 1;
$array['one'][2] = 3;
$array['one'][3] = 0;

$array['two'][0] = 22;
$array['two'][1] = 11;
$array['two'][2] = 33;
$array['two'][3] = 00;
```

Or any other random order, but having the same "random factor" in both?

For example, I want that `$array['one'][0]` and `$array['two'][0]` get shuffled to get `$array['one'][x]` and `$array['two'][x]` (`x` being a random key, but the SAME on both arrays).

Comment: Will the second array values *always* be two digits?

Comment: No, they are actually strings, I posted that as an example.

Comment: you might want to include the *exact* result you are after, to get the best answer.

Comment: I want that $array['one'][0] and $array['two'][0] get shuffled to get $array['one'][x] and $array['two'][x] (x being a random key, but the SAME on both arrays).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could work. It's similar to Mimikry's answer except this one will work even if you happen to have duplicate values in array one (this one doesn't use values of array one as keys of the temporary array).

Assuming both arrays are of the same size.

```
$c = count($array['one']);
$tmp = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
  $tmp[$i] = array($array['one'][$i], $array['two'][$i]);
}
shuffle($tmp);
for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
  $array['one'][$i] = $tmp[$i][0];
  $array['two'][$i] = $tmp[$i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 18):

```
$count = count($array['one']);
$order = range(1, $count);

shuffle($order);
array_multisort($order, $array['one'], $array['two']);
```

- Works with arrays with elements of any type (objects and arrays too).
- This way may by used with any number of arrays (not only two).
- Works with duplicated values.
- Clean code.

Comment: This doesn't work. The params are in the wrong order - array_multisort(array1,sorting order,sorting type,array2,array3...). Also the sorting order param value cannot be an array. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: A very old answer that still kicking +1

Comment: @DanteCullari this is working correctly. Check in interpreter. It is working because sort order and flags are optional. 
With array_multisort you may sort any array count.
Here you sort three arrays. Is just follow sorting of first "shuflled" array.
And order here is just name - is array with shuffled indexes - is not "sort" as described in docs.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully i get you right.

For your example above, this code should work. But it's pretty hacky...

```
$array['one'][0] = 'A';
$array['one'][1] = 'B';
$array['one'][2] = 'C';
$array['one'][3] = 'D';

$array['two'][0] = 'AA';
$array['two'][1] = 'BB';
$array['two'][2] = 'CC';
$array['two'][3] = 'DD';

// save the dependencies in tmp array
foreach ($array['two'] as $key => $val) {
    $tmp[$array['one'][$key]] = $val;
}

shuffle($array['one']);

// restore dependencies in tmp2 array
foreach ($array['one'] as $key => $val) {
    $tmp2[$key] = $tmp[$val];
}

// overwrite with restore array
$array['two'] = $tmp2;
```

var_dump($array):

```
array(2) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  ["two"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "BB"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "AA"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "CC"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "DD"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice, imho, is as follows:

```
$tmp = array_combine($array['one'],$array['two']);
shuffle($tmp);
$array['one'] = array_keys($tmp);
$array['two'] = array_values($tmp);
```

This is clear code and should be fast. No need to reinvent the wheel like in some other answers.

Comment: This does not work with duplicate values or non string/integer values in `$array['one']`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an example with multidimensional arrays but it works great for sorting multiple normal arrays the same way and with shuffle. Maybe it could be adapted for multidimensional arrays too. It does assume all arrays are the same length.

```
$array_count = count($array_1);

for($i=0;$i<=($array_count-1);$i++){
    $temp_array[$i] = $i;
}

shuffle($temp_array);

for($i=0;$i<=($array_count-1);$i++){
    $o = $temp_array[$i];
    $array_1_sorted[$i]=$array_1[$o];
    $array_2_sorted[$i]=$array_2[$o];
    $array_3_sorted[$i]=$array_3[$o];
}
```

This will give you new arrays which are all sorted the same random way. You could then set the old arrays equal to the new ones or keep them in-tact.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but your best bet is probably to put array 1 and array 2 into a multi-dimensional array and then random the primary array.  That will give you a random arrangement of values, but within each key will be the values of each array.  We could give you more specific answers if you can provide a bit more detail of exactly what you are doing.